# Подгрузка контента в конец блока

Tags: php, ajax

Имеется такой код:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.read-more',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id') || 0;
    // Вставляем полученный контент в HTML блок с id="content"
    $("#content").load("/catalog/",{action:"loadContent", id:id});
});
</script>
<div id="getContent">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <a class="read-more" data-id="<?php echo $vars['page']; ?>" href="#">Подробнее</a>
</div>
```

Когда нажимаю в первый раз на ссылку подгружаются данные, но если нажму во второй раз, то все что находится в блоке content перезапишется. Можно ли как нбудь не перезаписывать блок, а в конец добавлять данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените фрагмент вашего кода на такой вариант:

```
    $('#content')
    .append($('<div>')
    .load("/catalog/",{action:"loadContent", id:id}));
     });
```

Привожу рабочий пример, для наглядности:

```js
$(document).on('click','.read-more',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id') || 0;
    // Вставляем полученный контент в HTML блок с id="content"

    $('#content')
    .append($('<div>')
    .load("https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&sentences=1&start-with-lorem=1&format=html"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="getContent">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <a class="read-more" href="#">Подробнее</a>
</div>
```

Comment: почему то кидает со страницы host.ru/catalog на страницу host.ru/#

Comment: я вам намеренно привел рабочий пример, чтобы показать работоспособность подхода. Я вам готов помочь, но без кода - это сделать тяжеловато

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас загружу код

Comment: вот загрузил https://github.com/helldrg/site-catalog

Comment: На вопрос вы ответили, просто у меня не работает почему то, когда добавляю  .append($('<div>') на другую страницу перенаправляет

Comment: Странное поведение, ошибки есть?

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!!!!! Открыл консоль в хроме, а там скобку оказывается не поставил. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Будьте внимательны)!